# How to get grant token automatic

Tags: java, zoho

I must get access token with OAuth to read data from crm-zoho. But, everytime when I get access token, I must go to link: https://accounts.zoho.com/developerconsole to get new grant token after that I use grant token to get access token.

So, how can I get grant token automatic?

Comment: You can get the access token from the refresh token obtained in previous request. You only must use grant token if you change the scopes. Documentation [here](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/refresh.html)